# Converting string to float in Apple Swift yields value not identical to module error

Tags: ios, swift

I can print out my string `systemVersion` with `println` and I get:

> 8.0

But when I try to convert it using:

```
float(systemVersion)
```

I get two errors saying:

> Expected module member name after module name

&

> (@lvalue string) -> ST1 is not identical to module

What could that possibly mean?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `systemVersion.bridgeToObjectiveC().floatValue`, or `(systemVersion as NSString).floatValue`

Comment: I get "Could not find an overload for "init" that accepts the supplied arguments :(

Answer (score 0):

Being from a country where the decimal indicator is a "," and not a ".", I immediately smelled something.

Here, if you do this in a playground:

```
let systemVersion = "8.0"
Float(systemVersion)
```

you'll get a healthy float with the right value (notice the comma).

However, if you do the same with a dot:

```
let systemVersion = "8,0"
Float(systemVersion)
```

you'll get an error (could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments).

Could your problem be related to the decimal format in your country? Bye,